# Executing OpenGL Programs in Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu

I am trying to run opengl programs in linux, by connecting to a remote linux server. 
I connect using ssh and also provide the -X option, to use the X windowing system.

I am able to connect to the server and compile it. I successfully create the executable.
Now when I run the executable, I get an error. It says

```
freeglut (./lineTest):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

Where lineTest is the name of the executable.

When I compile the code, I link it to both the glut and GLU libraries.

Since the server is a remote server, I cannot make much driver changes.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do http://www.virtualgl.org/ might help.

Comment: Read about the `ssh -Y` option also.  Note that `-X` and `-Y` need to be enabled in the `sshd` config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line of the error message is a telltale:

```
freeglut (./lineTest):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
```

… it means, that the X11 server the client is connected to doesn't support setting a framebuffer format that's required by OpenGL.

The first course of action is using `glxinfo` to check, what's actually supported. Please run `glxinfo` as you would your program and post its output here (most likely there's no OpenGL support somewhere in the line). Also execute `glxinfo` locally, since it is your local machine, that'll do all the OpenGL work.